# Weird output from the sidenotes package

Tags: errors, xparse, sidenotes, bugs

Although I have been successfully using the `sidenotes` package for years, it suddenly stopped behaving. Here is the code,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. And some more. Here is a margin note \marginnote{I am a margin note}. 

Here is some text. And some more.  Here is a footnote\footnote{I am a footnote}. 

Here is some text. And some more. Here is a sidenote\sidenote{I am a side note}. 

\end{document}
```

that generates this output,

[image: ResultPDF]

Notice the "3sp" in the output! I also get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_let:D 
l.165 ... is a sidenote\sidenote{I am a side note}
```

and

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).<to be read again>
```

I believe this started occurring after I did an update of several dozens of packages through Tex Live Utility. It looks like something got corrupted somewhere, but I may be wrong.

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue.

Comment: Welcome! When did you update?

Comment: Do you have `xparse` version `2017/02/10 v6878` by any chance?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: @JPi Then either your copy of `xparse` is out of date or you have access to the promised update containing an interim fix.

Comment: @cfr Tex Live utility reveals that l3packages was updated with the latest version of xparse (2017/02/10).

Comment: That's why I always stay three or four months away from the latest updates.... ;-)

Comment: @JPi It'll still hit you in the end. The change to `xparse` breaks behaviour which was never supported. At least, that's what I was told. Of course, you might not be inadvertently relying on that behaviour and perhaps all the packages relying on it will get fixed within a quarter. Wouldn't hold your breath, though. That said, not updating if everything is working and you don't need new stuff is not bad advice. I don't think a 3/4 month hiatus is of much use, though. How on Earth do you update to 3/4 months ago anyway?

Comment: Always give the full error message. It is the `\tex_let` which is the give away here. The other errors could be many things and are very common. This one isn't nearly as common - I've only seen it in relation to this change in `xparse`.

Comment: At least three to four months.  Just going through the packaging system upgrade, which is updated reasonably quickly these days.

Comment: @JPi Oh, you use distro packages, you mean? That has its own problems, of course. Also, I can always downgrade, if necessary. `tlmgr` stores backups.

Comment: I do, actually.  Sure.  I can always upgrade.  ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to a change in `xparse.sty` version `2017/02/10 v6878`. My understanding was that an update addressing the issues caused by the change had been pushed to CTAN. However, it seems that is not (yet?) the case.

The issue affects the handling of `\NewDocumentCommand` when a macro is defined with no arguments. As I understand it, the change means that it is handled in the same way as definitions which take arguments. This breaks code which relied on the previous fast implementation, which was used when a definition specified a macro with no arguments.

You can work around the problem, not altogether satisfactorily, by using `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`. This isn't ideal, because it doesn't avoid overwriting an existing macro name, as `\NewDocumentCommand` does.

Alternatively, you can fall back to LaTeX 2e syntax, treating this as a gap in the current `expl3` implementation.

There currently appears to be no general agreement about the appropriate approach on the part of LaTeX 3 developers as it is a work-in-progress. However, apparently what `sidenotes` does was never supported. It just `happened to work`. But `sidenotes` is not alone and, moreover, it was not at all clear either that this wasn't supported or what should be done instead. Indeed, the latter is still not clear, as I understand it, but the subject of ongoing discussions.

However, all of that being said, your best bet is probably to workaround the problem as follows, avoiding the `expl3` issue in case of future changes, and relying on the stable LaTeX 2e implementation.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand* \@sidenotes@multisign {3sp}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Here is some text. And some more. Here is a margin note \marginnote{I am a margin note}.

Here is some text. And some more.  Here is a footnote\footnote{I am a footnote}.

Here is some text. And some more. Here is a sidenote\sidenote{I am a side note}.

\end{document}
```

[image: workaround for side notes]

Comment: Great, works perfectly. Thanks for your help. Not sure what this fix does, but my sidenotes are thriving again.

Comment: @Seb I *think* what it does is make `\@sidenotes@multisign` expandable, which is necessary for other things to work. It is because it doesn't expand, I *think*, that it complains about a missing number (it doesn't see `3` as a number) and then prints the value rather than using it. However, this is in the realm of grey boxes, for me, if not quite black ones. I hit this issue with the update and got help to fix it. So I just had to modify the fix for this case.

Comment: @Seb I do know it has *something* to do with expansion .... And the 2e approach I used here was recommended by people who should know ;).

Comment: (Not speaking for the LaTeX3 team.) As far as I'm concerned, `\@sidenotes@multisign` has no business being a document command: it is not markup that appears in the document itself.  It should probably be named something like `\l__sidenotes_multisign_tl` or similar, and be declared as a normal `expl3` token list.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I'm inclined to agree. However (1) the problem is not restricted to internal commands defined as document commands and (2) as far as I know `document command` is not defined anywhere. There is something of a general issue here in that `xparse` is an obvious place to look if you're hitting the limitations of the 2e definition macros, and that does not necessarily mean you know any `expl3`. Nor does `xparse` say what it shouldn't be used for. So, technically I'm inclined to agree, but from a user perspective, not so much.

Comment: @cfr: understood.  We'll try to improve the documentation about document commands, and to decide what to do about "document variables" or "document shorthands" which should be/need to be expandable.